# How do I unit test a SSDT project which uses sql server enterprise features against localdb?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, localdb

I have a SSDT project set up in VS which uses `SQL Server Enterprise Edition` features (e.g. data compression).

I'd like to be able to deploy this project to `localdb`, to be able to run unit tests against the database locally, before deploying to the CI database. However, `localdb` is an instance of `SQL Server Express Edition` which doesn't support data compression.

The error I get when I attempt to deploy is:

> SQL72014 .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Cannot enable compression for
>   object 'FooTable'. Only SQL Server Enterprise Edition supports
>   compression.

Potential solution #1: Shift all the data compression SQL to a `Post Deploy Script`, which is not run when deploying to `localdb`. This isn't ideal as the option would be hidden in source control, and wouldn't show in schema compare etc.

Potential solution #2: Replace the problem SQL with a `SQLCMD Variable` e.g. `$(WithPageCompression)` which will have empty value when deployed to `localdb` and the value `WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)` when deployed to the real database. This is an improvement on the above, but will become increasingly unwieldy as more options are set within the `WITH`.

Potential solution #3: Install a local instance of SQL Server on each developers machine. It looks like the [Developer Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-developers) would do the job (and is now free). It's looking like this might be the best solution and would come with other benefits, but the overhead of installing, configuring and maintaining this on the organisation's infrastructure makes this a pain.

What other options do I have?

Thanks

Comment: [localdb in SQL Server 2016 SP1 now supports most of this stuff.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released/)

Comment: Aha. Does this mean if I upgrade my SSDT version in Visual studio it will upgrade the bundled localdb from 2014 to 2016? Or would I have to wait for Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: I don't know which is why I didn't submit an answer. i'm not sure if you will need to wait for the next release of SSDT (not visual studio) or can just install SQL Server 2016 SP1 localdb standalone and have things work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [release of SQL Server 2016 SP1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released/), most functionality is now available in all editions. There are some limitations with LocalDB due to its design (it's even more lightweight than regular Express edition and doesn't support FileGroups / FileStream for this reason), but it's worth trying this out.

You can download Express or LocalDB [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express). LocalDB is also available in the [SSDT 17.0 RC release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx). This is currently in release candidate mode so we do not recommend it for production scenarios yet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to test anything 'serious' against SQL Server Express. I don't have time to engage in a flame war but Express is free for a reason (see ;you get what you pay for...') One way or another you want to test against a version of SQL Server that matches your production version exactly or you will spend an inordinate amount of time discovering and fixing incompatibilities.  The hardware does not necessarily have to match but you should, as much as possible, match software between test and production.

Why can't you install the developer edition where Express is installed?

Comment: The express instance I'm referring to is actually the 'localdb' instance bundled with visual studio on each developers machine. I'm looking into getting Developer Edition installed on each users machine, but the organisation I'm working for has a strict software approval process and this could be a pain. Also it raises the barriers for a new developer which isn't ideal. But you're right ideally all tests (even locally) should be run against a production-like environment.